# Linux tr command

Tags: linux, csh

I'm relatively new to programming in c-shell and I'm having a problem with the tr command. When I execute the script, the error message I receive is "tr command not found". I'm also trying to display the contents of a file in foreach loop that I've assigned to a variable. Would this actually only print the name of the file path or its contents?  Here's my code :

```
#! /bin/csh

set path = /home/students/fall2012/crn12143/ford/friend_list

foreach i ($path)
echo $i | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
end
```

Comment: Don't code scripts in `csh`. http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Comment: will only print the name of the file. use `cat $i` to print the file(s), one at a time to your screen. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I figured it out! That displayed the contents of the file perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are breaking the path so it can no longer find `tr`. Change the path like:

```
set path=(/home/students/fall2012/crn12143/ford/friend_list $path)
```

Since you aren't really using `path` like it should be used, you should consider renaming that variable to something else.

If you want to still remove most of the path, use the full path for the `tr` command:

```
echo $i | /path/to/tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
```

Comment: is lower case path and upper case path same?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im, that's a good question. I had both in my .cshrc so I just pasted them both here. I am not sure what the difference is. I need to remember to comment these changes so I remember why I made them.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Unix paths are case sensitive.

Comment: @JonathanRioux I meant `path`, the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You are redefining the PATH envrionment variable, which is not good.

You should instead use a different variable name like:

```
set folder = /home/students/fall2012/crn12143/ford/friend_list
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help, I renamed the path variable to folder and I got the script to convert it from lower case to uppercase. How can I extract the contents of this folder and print them to screen using the foreach?